# How to record FLAC format in iOS 11+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-speech-api, flac

I changed the code in [AudioController.swift](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming/Speech/AudioController.swift) to:

```swift
...
// Set format for mic input (bus 1) on RemoteIO's output scope
var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
...
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatFLAC
asbd.mFormatFlags = kAppleLosslessFormatFlag_16BitSourceData
...
```

and [SpeechRecognitionService.swift](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming/Speech/SpeechRecognitionService.swift) to

```swift
...
// send an initial request message to configure the service
let recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig()
recognitionConfig.encoding =  .flac
...
```

I tried tinkering around with AudioStreamBasicDescription.mFormatFlags but cannot find the right flags for Google Speech API to recognize the format.

How do I make iOS to record FLAC using the given iOS API?

Comment: Does the speech API return a particular error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906765/chunked-encoding-using-flac-on-ios

Comment: AVAudioRecorder can directly be used to record Flac format

Comment: @ChristianAbella The link that you pinged records PCM and then converts to FLAC

Comment: @jspcal The code just halts for a response from AudioRecorder, probably something that I did. I can't debug it since there is no error.

Comment: @iOSGeek Any code examples or documentation links that you know of?

Comment: please check some part of code that I have used to record audio directly in Flac format @Raviteja

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
/// Common Struct 
struct Manager
{    
    //Required Objects - AVFoundation
    ///AVAudio Session
    static var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!

    ///AVAudio Recorder
    static var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?
}
```

**Permissions**

```
func CheckForPermission() {
    Manager.recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try Manager.recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
        Manager.recordingSession.requestRecordPermission({ (allowed) in
            if allowed {
                Manager.micAuthorised = true
            }
            else {
                Manager.micAuthorised = false
            }
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async  {
            //Reload Label text in Home screen
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLabel"), object: nil)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Failed to set Category", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**Recorder Setting & Recording with flac**

```
func startMainRecording() {
    print("Main Recording session is created")

    //Get unique File Name
    Manager.audioName = getUniqueName()
    let AudioFileName = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(Manager.audioName).flac")
    print("New Path: \(AudioFileName)")

    //Recorder Settings
    let settings: [String: Any] = [
        /// Format Flac
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatFLAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        ]

    //Handler
    do {
        //Activate session when required

        //try Manager.recordingSession.setPreferredSampleRate(44000)
        try Manager.recordingSession.setActive(true)

        //Start Recording With Audio File name
        Manager.recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: AudioFileName, settings: settings)
        Manager.recorder?.delegate = self
        Manager.recorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
    }
    catch
    {
        //Finish Recording with a Error
        print("Error Handling: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        /// Saved here if any error occur while recording Just case
        self.finishRecording(success: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: FLAC if I remember correctly needs the sample rate to be 44100, I will try this and see.

Comment: I used a low sample rate just to keep my file smaller in size as I was required to upload in Database

Comment: Did this helped ?

Comment: @iOSGeek How to stop recording and is this possible to record video with flac encoded audio ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I got moved to a different project, never really got to the bottom of this. I hope your answer will help anyone that has the same problem